# Overriding abstract classes in VB6

Tags: class, vb6, overriding, abstract

I already know that you create an Interface within VB6.
Classes that implement an interface must implement ALL routines.
Is there a way to create something like an abstract class that may implement some routines.
Derived class must implement the abstract routines and may override the routines already implemented by the abstract class.

Please notice that we're talking about VB6 and not VB.NET or whatsoever.
Thank you

Comment: No easy way. Here are some links to descriptions of some workarounds. [MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260821(v=vs.60).aspx) and [Rockford Lhotka](http://www.lhotka.net/Article.aspx?id=5f76a91c-5a75-49e1-9379-6d2807653b68).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One work-around I use is to have an instance of the base class as a private member:

```
Implements Shape

Dim base as Shape
Dim radius as Single 

Public Function Shape_Area() as Single
  Shape_Area = pi*pi*radius
End Sub

Public Function Shape_PenColour() as Long
  Shape_PenColour = base.PenColour()   ' let the base do its thing
End Function
```

You could work up a hierarchy like that (for Square):

```
Implements Shape

Dim base as Rectangle

Public Function Shape_Area() as Single
  Shape_Area = base.Area() ' which is Rectangle.Shape_Area which then calls the Shape.Area
End Sub
```

It does means that each class has to really know about the one it derives from. That may or may not be an issue for you. I have used it and it works well.

It does mean you have to do more work and each class explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic 6 does not support implementation inheritance, only interface inheritance.  You can read more about it [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yet634fk(v=vs.90).aspx).  There's a nice article [here](http://www.shomsky.com/Technical/Articles/ImplementingInterfacesInVB6.asp) about interfaces and inheritance in VB6 that may lead you to a solution to your problem within VB6 capabilities.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. There's a work-around that I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A work-around (not a solution):

An interface, for instance, specifies routine A and B, implementing the second one.
A derived class has a private member being an instance of the interface.
The implementation of the routine B simply invokes that method on its private member.
Of course, we're dealing with 2 different objects but in some cases this may be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation inheritance is over-rated and almost always ends up with complicated designs.

What you want to do achieve (provide base impl, reduce repeating code in derived classes, etc) can be done with composition and events

Consider interface `IBase`

```
Public Function GetArea() As Double

End Function
```

interface `IDerived`

```
Property Get Base() As IBase

End Property
```

Common implementation `StdBaseImpl` of `IBase`

```
Implements IBase

Event CustomizeArea(Value As Double)

Public Function GetArea() As Double
    GetArea = 42
    RaiseEvent CustomizeArea(GetArea)
End Function

Private Function IBase_GetArea() As Double
    IBase_GetArea = GetArea
End Function
```

Then for derived classes you use composition and choose which base events to implement

```
Implements IDerived

Private WithEvents m_oBase As StdBaseImpl

Private Property Get IDerived_Base() As IBase
    Set IDerived_Base = m_oBase
End Property

Private Sub m_oBase_CustomizeArea(Value As Double)
    Value = Value + 10
End Sub
```

You can design bases with `BeforeXxx` + `Cancel` and `AfterXxx` events. You can sink multiple bases and coordinate them.